# Python: Manipulating list of Color objects?

Tags: python, string

I'm using the colour package to create a gradient of colors, like this:

```
from colour import Color
orange = Color("#e65318")
turquoise = Color("#3297A5")
palette_list = list(orange.range_to(turquoise,10))
```

the output is a list, like this:

```
[<Color #e65318>, <Color #de911b>, <Color #d7c71f>, <Color #a7cf22>, <Color #6fc825>, <Color #3dc128>, <Color #2bb944>, <Color #2db36f>, <Color #30ac94>, <Color #3297a5>]
```

and what I would really like, is this:

```
['#e65318', '#de911b', '#d7c71f', '#a7cf22', '#6fc825', '#3dc128', '#2bb944', '#2db36f', '#30ac94', '#3297a5']
```

So far, I've tried `ai_palette_list.remove('Color')`

which returns `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`.

I am thinking this is a pretty general problem, but can't seem to find any sane, systematic way of going about removing the word 'Color' and returning a string.

Comment: which "colour package" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This list comprehension should accomplish that:

```
[c.hex for c in palette_list]
```

As @LeopoldVonBuschLight pointed out, what you have is a list of Color objects, this list comprehension gets the .hex value of each object and puts it into a list.

Answer (score 1):

The list you are printing out is a list of objects, not strings; `<Color #e65318>`is a Color object. From the docs it looks like you can get the hex representation using `hex` or `hex_l`: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colour